Projecting 2D mouse coordinates to 3D
I am looking to implement a simple 3D triangle creator in JavaFX, for that I need to be able to convert the 2D mouse position to 3D.
After searching for a while, it seems like the only way to do this is to use the internal CameraHelper class, specifically it's pickProjectPlane(camera, x, y) method
This method however does not seem to work as I'd expect with my setup, where i have a SubScene for the 3D scene
Here is some example code, my goal is to have a box rendered at the click position, as if i get that correctly working, creating the triangle creator will be very simple
public class JavaFX3DPickingTest extends Application {

    private SubScene scene3D;
    private OrbitCamera orbitCamera;
    private Group sceneGroup = new Group();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
        create3DSubScene(800, 600);
        pane.getChildren().add(scene3D);
        // for reference
        Box referenceBox = new Box(1, 1, 1);
        sceneGroup.getChildren().add(referenceBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600, true);
        // even if the listener is added to scene3D, it produces the same result
        scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            // only pick when alt is down
            if (!event.isAltDown()) {
                return;
            }
            double x = event.getSceneX();
            double y = event.getSceneY();
            // these values are too huge, clearly they need to be scaled, but I don't know by what factor exactly
            Point3D pos = CameraHelper.pickProjectPlane(orbitCamera.camera, x, y);
            System.out.println("Pos: " + pos);
            Box box = new Box(1, 1, 1);
            box.setTranslateX(pos.getX());
            box.setTranslateY(pos.getY());
            box.setTranslateZ(pos.getZ());
            sceneGroup.getChildren().add(box);
        });
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void create3DSubScene(double width, double height) {
        scene3D = new SubScene(sceneGroup, width, height, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        scene3D.setFill(Color.rgb(25, 25, 25));
        orbitCamera = new OrbitCamera(scene3D, sceneGroup);
    }

    private static class OrbitCamera {

        private final SubScene subScene;
        private final Group root3D;

        private final double MAX_ZOOM = 300.0;

        public OrbitCamera(SubScene subScene, Group root) {
            this.subScene = subScene;
            this.root3D = root;
            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            camera.setNearClip(0.1D);
            camera.setFarClip(MAX_ZOOM * 1.15D);
            root3D.getChildren().add(camera); // do we really need to do this

            updateCamera();

            subScene.setCamera(camera);
            subScene.setOnScroll(event -> {
                double zoomFactor = 1.05;
                double deltaY = event.getDeltaY();

                if (deltaY < 0) {
                    zoomFactor = 2.0 - zoomFactor;
                }
                double z = cameraDistance / zoomFactor;
                z = Math.max(1, Math.min(MAX_ZOOM, z));
                cameraDistance = z;
                updateCamera();
            });

            subScene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
                if (event.isAltDown()) {
                    return;
                }
                mousePosX = event.getSceneX();
                mousePosY = event.getSceneY();
            });

            subScene.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
                if (event.isAltDown()) {
                    return;
                }
                double modifier = 1.0;
                double modifierFactor = 0.3;

                if (event.isControlDown()) modifier = 0.1;
                if (event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) modifier = 0.035;

                double sceneX = event.getSceneX();
                double sceneY = event.getSceneY();
                double mouseDeltaX = sceneX - mousePosX;
                double mouseDeltaY = sceneY - mousePosY;
                mousePosX = sceneX;
                mousePosY = sceneY;

                if (event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                    double dx = -mouseDeltaX * modifierFactor * modifier * 2.0;
                    double dy = -mouseDeltaY * modifierFactor * modifier * 2.0;
                    translation.setX(translation.getX() + dx);
                    translation.setY(translation.getY() + dy);
                } else if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    double dx = mouseDeltaX * modifierFactor * modifier * 2.0;
                    double dy = -mouseDeltaY * modifierFactor * modifier * 2.0;
                    yaw += dx;
                    pitch += dy;
                }

                updateCamera();
            });
        }

        public void updateCamera() {
            Affine affine = new Affine();
            Rotate rotateY = new Rotate(yaw, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
            Rotate rotateX = new Rotate(pitch, Rotate.X_AXIS);
            affine.append(rotateY);
            affine.append(rotateX);
            affine.append(new Translate(translation.getX(), translation.getY(), -cameraDistance));
            position = affine.transform(0, 0, 0);
            camera.getTransforms().setAll(affine);
        }


        private final PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
        private double cameraDistance = 30;
        private Point3D position;
        private final Translate translation = new Translate(0.1889, -3.4019, -cameraDistance);
        private double yaw = 1.0;
        private double pitch = -19.4;
        private double mousePosX = 0;
        private double mousePosY = 0;
    }

}

Example of the exact functionality I'd like to achieve:
https://imgur.com/0uTWv5i
Update: it seems like picking with fixedEyeAtCameraZero = false, it produces the z values i would expect, but the issue is that this breaks my whole camera implementation, the docs also say that if i plan to move the camera, i should have fixedEyeAtCameraZero true

"I need to be able to convert the 2D mouse position to 3D." -> Do you need to do that though?  JavaFX natively supports 3D picking.

This doesn't do quite what I'd expect, if i create a virtual plane (assume just a Box) and then use the PickResult constructor that takes in a target, sceneX, sceneY, It always gives me values in the parent scene space so if i translate the box, it won't even be visible

"then use the PickResult constructor" -- I believe @jewelsea is saying you should use MouseEvent::getPickResult, not create a new PickResult.

Also, does doing the logic in a mouse handler added to the SubScene (instead of the Scene)  help?

Oh sorry i misunderstood then, but that requires me to intersect with some object and even if i do create a 'virtual' object to intersect with, it still seems to give me z = 0 most of the time, the only time where it gives anything z = 0 is if the object has a z translation (in that case z = object z translation)
If i make fixedEyeAtCameraZero to false, it seems to work exactly as I'd expect most of the time, however this breaks the current camera implementation, I believe to adjust most of the parameters, also seems like i still have to use the internal CameraHelper#pickProjectPlane method

And doing the logic in a mouse handler added to the SubScene doesn't seem to change much unfortunately

"requires me to intersect with some object" -> if there is nothing to intersect with, I don't understand the meaning of "projecting 2D mouse coordinates in 3D".  I think you need to intersect with something, e.g. a plane.  That is likely what the pickProjectPlane method you are calling is doing.  If your "virtual object" is a plane at the correct distance and orientation, then picking three points on it will define a triangle.  Here is the math if you feel insane and wish to do this from first principles.

From the doc I linked: "This is an entirely mathematical exercise - we don't use any OpenGL code or draw any graphics - this means that it will apply to any 3d application the same way. The mathematical subject is usually called geometric intersection testing."

I don't see that part in the doc you linked, but either way I don't see how i can use the picking api to get a 3D point from clicking an arbitrary location in space
